# How to make SCTP checksum non-zero using C programming

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, sctp

I wrote a simple SCTP client/server, and I observed SCTP handshaking via Wireshark. The checksums of all SCTP packets are always zero in Wireshark.

How do I make a non-zero SCTP checksum?

The following are installed libraries on Ubuntu 18.04

```
libsctp-dev:amd64    1.0.17+dfsg-2  
libsctp1:amd64       1.0.17+dfsg-2  
lksctp-tools         1.0.17+dfsg-2
```

sctp-server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int sockfd, client_sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, client_addr;
    struct sctp_initmsg initmsg;
    int len;
    int addr_count = 1;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_SCTP);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"socket descriptor is invalid.");
        exit(1);
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12345);

    int brst = sctp_bindx(sockfd,(struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr,addr_count,SCTP_BINDX_ADD_ADDR);
    if(brst == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error while binding address.");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&initmsg,0,sizeof(initmsg));
    initmsg.sinit_max_instreams = 2;
    initmsg.sinit_num_ostreams = 2;
    brst = setsockopt(sockfd,IPPROTO_SCTP,SCTP_INITMSG,&initmsg,sizeof(initmsg));
    if(brst != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error while setting sctp options.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    listen(sockfd,5);
    while (1)
    {
        len = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &len);

        if(client_sockfd == -1)
        {
            fprintf(stderr,"error while accepting connection, continue.\n");
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("New client\n");
            close(client_sockfd);
        }
    }
}
```

sctp-client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/sctp.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    sctp_assoc_t associd;
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in *addrs;
    int brst;
    struct sctp_initmsg initmsg;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_SCTP);
    if(sockfd < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"error while initializing socket.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    addrs = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.1.197");
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(12345);

    memcpy(addrs,&serv_addr,sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    memset(&initmsg, 0, sizeof(initmsg));
    initmsg.sinit_max_instreams = 2;
    initmsg.sinit_num_ostreams = 2;

    brst = sctp_connectx(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &serv_addr, 1, &associd);
    if(brst < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "can not connect to host.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("connect ok %d\n", brst);
    }

    close(sockfd);
}
```

Compile

```
$ gcc sctp-server.c -lsctp -o server
$ gcc sctp-client.c -lsctp -o client
```

Wireshark

```
Frame 828: 100 bytes on wire (800 bits), 100 bytes captured (800 bits)
Linux cooked capture
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.1.197, Dst: 192.168.1.197
Stream Control Transmission Protocol, Src Port: 49208 (49208), Dst Port: 12345 (12345)
    Source port: 49208
    Destination port: 12345
    Verification tag: 0x00000000
    [Association index: 0]
    Checksum: 0x00000000 [unverified]
    [Checksum Status: Unverified]
    INIT chunk (Outbound streams: 10, inbound streams: 65535)
        Chunk type: INIT (1)
            0... .... = Bit: Stop processing of the packet
            .0.. .... = Bit: Do not report
        Chunk flags: 0x00
        Chunk length: 52
        Initiate tag: 0xd15eb4e4
        Advertised receiver window credit (a_rwnd): 106496
        Number of outbound streams: 10
        Number of inbound streams: 65535
        Initial TSN: 1069541083
        IPv4 address parameter (Address: 192.168.1.197)
        IPv4 address parameter (Address: 172.17.0.1)
        Supported address types parameter (Supported types: IPv4)
        ECN parameter
        Forward TSN supported parameter
```

Comment: @John Kugelman, Sorry I edit the question and add more details.

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I've voted to reopen the question. Please be patient -- reopening could take a little while.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance you disabled SCTP checksums in the linux kernel as mentioned in this [patch](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netdev/patch/1234550024-30915-2-git-send-email-vladislav.yasevich@hp.com/). To verify this run the command `sysctl /sys/module/sctp/parameters/sctp_checksum_disable`. If the output is `1` then change it to `0` and try your test again.